# Laravel validation custom rule

Tags: php, sql, laravel, validation, rule

How to do that this function would look for a row in table not by given name ***John*** but by inputed ***'name'*** ?

```
public function validation($request)
{
    return $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'code' =>  ['required',Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', '=', 'John');

        }), ],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your problem description

Comment: I want that this validation would check database table for an exist 'code' that user inputed it and condition where 'code' must be in a same row in table as 'name' that user inputed in a form.

Comment: is it working for name='john'

Comment: yes, its working

Comment: then just replace `John` to `$request->name`

Comment: `$query->where('name', '=', $request->name);`  I get  `Undefined variable: request`

Comment: `function ($query) use ($request) { .... }` and then you can use `$request->name`

Answer (score 1):

Check your param and change 'John' to request->name

```html
public function validation(Request $request){
  return $this->validate($request, [
          'name'      => 'required|max:255',
          'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
          'code'      => [
                          'required',
                          Rule::exists('users')
                              ->where('name', $request->name)
                        ],
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `use` keyword for this and pass the `$request` object inside this like

```
public function validation($request)
{
    return $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'code' =>  ['required',Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', '=', $request->name);

        }), ],
    ]);
}
```

or, you can use like this without passing a callback function in `where` as

```
public function validation($request)
{
    return $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'code' =>  array('required',Rule::exists('users')->where('name', '=', $request->name);),
    ]);
}
```